# 301 Redirect issues with WordPress Multisite install

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

I've seen a bunch of posts on SO and other sites or this but none of my methods are working. I think possibly because my subdomain structure is different.

I have a WordPress Multisite install with three sites. Got in a bit late, so I have to have the subdomains appear at the end of the URL. So for example, one of the URL's is dairyking.com/dairyberries/ and not dairyberries.dairyking.com

So I have this for one of my redirects in my /htaccess:

```
# Rewrite rules which will only apply to dairyberries.com/dairyking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dairyberries\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^dairyking/category/recipe/$ http://dairyberries.com/dairyking/category/recipe/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

But the reidrect still isn't occurring. So what can I do to get this code to work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /multi_website/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /multi_website/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /multi_website/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

- **Add This to your .htaccess file**. See the screenshots below. This will
  work 100%.

  http://prntscr.com/o5t989 .
  https://prnt.sc/o5t9zl

  multi_website/wp-admin/ (main website) 
  multi_website/abc/wp-admin/
  multi_website/pqr/wp-admin/